# Round() not working

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

```
D1_inv
Out[23]: [0.024799999999999999, 0.029600000000000001, 0.035799999999999998]
```

I'm trying to round these figures upto 4 decimal places. I've used this:

```
for i in D1_inv:
    round(i,4)
```

But the output remains the same as above. Can somebody help me here?

Comment: `round(i,4)` **returns** the rounded value. Instead of saving it into a variable, you discard it.

Comment: Well once you round them you need to place them back in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
D1_inv = [0.024799999999999999, 0.029600000000000001, 0.035799999999999998]

for i in D1_inv:
    print round(float(i), 4)
```

Output:

```
0.0248
0.0296
0.0358
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a perfect case for list comprehension:

```
D1_inv = [round(i,4) for i in D1_inv]
print(D1_inv)
#[0.0248, 0.0296, 0.0358]
```

Comment: Your code is the same as mine. Output remains the same.

Comment: Certainly my code is not the same as yours. I included the ouput of my code. It is different from yours, too.

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't change the output in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is floating-point errors.  Often it's not mathematically possible to represent a base 10 decimal in base 2 (i.e. as a `float`) exactly, so your computer gets as close as it can.  But if your output style is set to show many decimal places, these "errors" will show up.

`round` doesn't help because its output is still a `float`.  You can't really fix this in any simple way, as it is an artefact of binary math.  Some options are:

- Turn the decimals into fractions using [`frac`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frac)
- Fix the diplayed precision of your output using `.format` (but this makes them strings)
- fix the displayed precision of your interpeter (which is an interpreter-specific operation).

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the result.

```
for i, x in enumerate(D1_inv):
    D1_inv[i] = round(x, 4)
```

Comment: Hi, your code gives me this: <enumerate at 0xb30a918>

Comment: No, it does not.